# Rails -> do something with "updated_at" like "set_primary_key" for the id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, field-names

have a legacy table with a field "LastModifiedDate", and I want to use that column as my "updated_at" column.

Is there any way to tell Rails to use that field?

Or, let me rephrase. :)  ... *How* can I tell Rails to use that field?  :)

Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733630/renaming-the-created-at-updated-at-columns-of-activerecord-rails

Answer (score 0):

Hi You may use `after_update` to change value of that column

Comment: Would this allow Rails to use this column magically?  Or with this method, will I need to set the value explicitly myself.

Comment: Other than setting it for you, `updated_at` doesn't really do any magic for you.  You could add an `updated_at` method to your model that returns the `LastModifiedDate` as a `Time` and get the effect you want.

Comment: If I also added an  "updated_at="  method, would Rails do its setting magic as well?