# ruby activerecord how to use alternate updated_at column

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to use Rails3 with an existing db schema.  The timestamp fields updated_at and created_at need to be mapped to created and modified on the db.

Is there a way to tell activerecord to use alternate column names?

Thanks in advance, Chris

EDIT

Could it be done by having this in a file in the model directory:

```
module ActiveRecord

  module Timestamp
    def timestamp_attributes_for_update #:nodoc:
      [:modified, :updated_on]
    end

    def timestamp_attributes_for_create #:nodoc:
      [:created, :created_on]
    end
  end

end
```

Comment: Mmm - wonder what happened to Chuck's answer of overriding created_at/updated_at - seems to be working for me, perhaps I am missing something...

Comment: Please stop using monkey patching. Here's a better way: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13457972/264409

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that without overriding `timestamp_attributes_for_update` in [ActiveRecord:: Timestamp](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb).

A simple workaround would be to use a `before_update` callback in the model.

```
before_update :set_modified_time

private
  def set_modified_time
    self.modified = Time.now
  end
```

Comment: You'd also need a `before_save` callback. And you're correct, it's not possible without overriding ActiveRecord::Timestamp as the column names are hard-coded there.

Comment: You don't necessarily need to use `before_save`, and if you did use that, you could use it in place of `before_update` as it is called in both cases. I guess it depends on whether the column in the db had a default to set it to the current time or whether you wanted it to be nil if it hadn't been modified yet, but @Chris didn't mention that in his question.

Comment: How do I go about the overriding timestamp_attributes_for_update option - is it sufficient to have a file in the model directory containing :  see edit to question...

Comment: @Chris, What you have in your question will work fine, but I'd put it in an initializer or in lib and require it in application.rb. @Andrew, sorry, I just realised that I completely missed that he was wanting to set the `created` attribute as well. Apologies.