# Rails timestamps: updated_on / created_on versus created_at / updated_at

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm writing a Rails migration to create a table:

```
create_table(TABLE, :options => FEDERATED_TABLE_CONFIG % TABLE) do |table|
  table.timestamps
  table.string :country_tld
end
```

This results in the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sites` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_tld` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=FEDERATED DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 CONNECTION='mysql://foo:bar@localhost/baz/sites'
```

Tragically, my foreign data source uses the old-school Rails `updated_on` and `created_on` columns for its timestamps. Of course I can get around this:

```
create_table(TABLE, :options => FEDERATED_TABLE_CONFIG % TABLE) do |table|
  table.datetime :created_on, :updated_on
  table.string :country_tld
end
```

If there's a trivial way to still use timestamps and get the behaviour I want, I'd love to hear about it. And no, I don't consider [monkey-patching `ActiveRecord::Timestamp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733630/renaming-the-created-at-updated-at-columns-of-activerecord-rails/3981571#3981571) a trivial way of doing it, considering this just affects one migration. ;)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your question is here? [ActiveRecord::Timestamp](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb) will use the `created_on` and `updated_on` columns just the same as the `_at` versions (See lines 84 & 88).

As an aside, you needn't loop through an array to generate the datetimes in a one-liner. Use this instead:

```
table.datetime :created_on, :updated_on
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that you could create multiple columns at once with the ["sexy syntax"](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#creating-a-table).

Comment: My question is: can I use the `#timestamps` helper to create the old-style columns?

Answer (score 5):

The rails source for `timestamps` is:

```
def add_timestamps(table_name)
  add_column table_name, :created_at, :datetime
  add_column table_name, :updated_at, :datetime
end
```

So you can see there's no way to customize the column names. To be honest, the best way is the one you suggest. I personally avoid stuff like:

```
%w{created_on updated_on}.each {|col| table.datetime col.to_sym }
```

And just write out the actual `add_column` commands, it's more verbose bit also easier to read.