# Rails3 timestamp mapping to legacy table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a legacy table with a column for the last update timestamp.
Now I do want to tell my model that the rails attribute updated_at is mapped to the legacy column.

```
alias_attribute :updated_at, :lastcall
```

Now I can access the column but it's not getting updated when i update the object.
So how can I use the rails timestamps with an legacy column?
Best,
P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a 'proper' way of doing it, but you could do it with a before_save or before_update filter on the model.

```
class LegacyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_update :update_lastcall

  private

  def update_lastcall
    self.lastcall = Time.now
  end

end
```

If you don't want to get the model messy you could put it into an Observer.

Comment: hey that's the way I solved it, but it thought there might be a another solution by mapping the timestamp fields to your own db columns

Answer (score 2):

Try to add this as well, which will alias the setter method.

```
alias_attribute :updated_at=, :lastcall=
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd also like to [draw your attention to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3981571/194869), if your timestamp column names are site-wide (as mine are). I didn't want to clutter up my models, and fortunately, you can monkey-patch `ActiveRecord::Timestamp`. I placed the below into a dir named `lib/rails_ext/active_record.rb` (I'm an organization freak) and called it with a `require 'rails_ext/active_record'` declaration in one of my initializers in `config/initializers/`.

```
module ActiveRecord
  module Timestamp
    private
    def timestamp_attributes_for_update #:nodoc:
      [:modified_time, :updated_at, :updated_on, :modified_at]
    end
    def timestamp_attributes_for_create #:nodoc:
      [:created_date, :created_at, :created_on]
    end
  end
end
```

My custom attributes ended up being `:modified_time` and `:created_date`. You'd specify your `:lastcall` column in one of those (`timestamp_attributes_for_update`, I'm assuming). No mucking with your models required.