# How to set default value of column to current time with ActiveRecord?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I got a field in MYSQL called "date_added". I want this to have the value Time.now.to_i as its default value (in other words, the time the record was added). I know a similar column is added for free in ActiveRecord, but ignoring that... how can I add this default value?

:default => ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `before_create`:

```
class SomeModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_date_added

  protected

  def set_date_added
     self.date_added = Time.now.to_i
  end
end
```

This gets called right before an object is saved for the first time, exactly the conditions you want.

Alternatively, you can use a hack to rename the default activerecord `created_at` to `date_added` by following the answers here: [Renaming the created_at, updated_at columns of ActiveRecord/Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/733630/renaming-the-created-at-updated-at-columns-of-activerecord-rails)
See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html for more information on callbacks.