# Replacing created_at update_at by CREATEDAT UPDATEDAT Active_admin

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have replace the naming convension  I have replace created_at & update_at by CREATEDATE, :MODIFYDATE Active_admin
But it is not updated automatically
Following is the Code

```
class DeviceMaster < ActiveRecord::Base

  set_table_name "MDDMT"
  set_primary_key "DMTRFNUM"
  attr_accessible :DMTDEVICEID, :DMTISACTIVE, :CREATEDBY, :MODIFIEDBY, :CREATEDATE, :MODIFYDATE, 
                    :EXTRAFIELD1, :EXTRAFIELD2, :EXTRAFIELD3, :EXTRAFIELD4
  alias_attribute :created_at, :MODIFYDATE
  alias_attribute :updated_at, :MODIFYDATE
end
```

So how can I achieved the created_at updated_at columns functionality for CREATEDATE,:MODIFYDATE
Is aliasing column is right way or I need to be write separate callback in model?
Regards,

Comment: Have you checked out http://stackoverflow.com/a/3981571/2622934?

Comment: Its not working for update condition

Comment: Are you editing multiple tables in one form using something like `fields_for`?  In that case, the parent record's update timestamp will only be updated if data that resides on the parent table is updated, not when data on the child tables are updated.

Comment: No I m having only single table which is shown above
I using active_admin

Comment: Can you include your `schema.rb` info for this table, your ActiveRecord Timestamp override code, and the code from your update action in the controller?