# Change name of updated_at column in ActiveRecord / Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, jruby, jrubyonrails

I'm building a JRuby on Rails app for a legacy database. None of the tables have a 'created_at' column (so I can just go ahead and add that), but all of them have a 'modtime' column instead of an 'updated_at' column. I can't change all of the column names from 'modtime' to 'updated_at' in the db since much of the java code and sql functions use this column name. It would be possible to simply add an 'updated_at' column to all the tables, but this would be confusing and less than ideal.

How I can get ActiveRecord to use 'modtime' as a column name instead of 'updated_at'?

Comment: Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3981571/2622934

Comment: Thanks guys, I read that answer but I don't really understand it: Where does this active_record.rb file go? What is the meaning of "create a file called that in the initializers"? I assume that I put :modtime in the array I pass to the timestamp_attributes_for_update method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what you need to do for ActiveRecord to use modtime as its update column:

Create a file in the config/initializers directory named active_record_patch.rb

```
# config/initializers/active_record_patch.rb
module ActiveRecord
  module Timestamp      

    private

      def timestamp_attributes_for_update #:nodoc:
        [:modtime, :updated_on, :modified_at]
      end
  end
end
```

What you are doing here is overriding ActiveRecord::Timestamp's `timestamp_attributes_for_update` method which it uses to identify the names of its update attributes. The file needs to be put in config/initializers since all files in initializers get run once your Rails app loads.

This is a monkey patch and overrides the normal behavior of ActiveRecord::Timestamp which may break when you use a different version of ActiveRecord.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! This is a clear and concise answer and works for me on Rails 4.0.2.

Comment: This monkey patch quietly breaks a normal behavior of Timestamp because original column names are [:updated_on, :updated_at](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb#L91). `updated_at` column that was generated by default rails generator for other AR models wouldn't be updated. Please clarify your answer.