# Can I modify the timestamps column name in Rails 4.2 from created_at to like created

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I want to change the `timestamps` default column names from 
`created_at` to `createdDatetime`
and `updated_at` to `updatedDatetime`.

Is there any way to do so?  When I migrate it, can I create these names as I wish?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Renaming the created\_at, updated\_at columns of ActiveRecord/Rails](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/733630/renaming-the-created-at-updated-at-columns-of-activerecord-rails)

Comment: Don't that works with rails 4.2

Answer (score 3):

The quickest, most flexible solution that doesn't involve monkey-patching is this:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_create :set_time_stamps
  before_save :set_time_stamps

private
  def set_time_stamps
    self.createdDatetime = DateTime.now if self.new_record?
    self.updatedDatetime = DateTime.now
  end
end
```

You are in complete control in each model class (database table) of which column names are updated.  You can control the format if you choose, in case the field is a timestamp, milli-time, or even a formatted string (it happens!).  This solution is highly likely to survive major version upgrades of Rails, since this is a part of the public interface for ActiveRecord.

If you have a number of models that behave identically, you can either make a base class or module to handle it.

The base class approach:

```
class TimeStamper < ActiveRecord::Base
  # TimeStamper is not intended for single-table inheritance
  self.abstract_class = true

  before_create :set_time_stamps
  before_save :set_time_stamps

private
  def set_time_stamps
    self.createdDatetime = DateTime.now if self.new_record?
    self.updatedDatetime = DateTime.now
  end
end
```

And then derive your models from this, like so:

```
class Product < TimeStamper
  # inherits all of the ActiveRecord::Base and TimeStamper functionality
end
```

In your migration, you'd simply need to include the fields like you would any others:

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      # Product fields

      t.datetime :createdDatetime, null: false
      t.datetime :updatedDatetime, null: false
    end
  end
end
```

You will have to add those manually, but it's not an onerous task if that's what you need to do.  Rails gives you the flexibility to deviate from convention when your requirements dictate, and in this case the deviation is both benign and simple to handle manually.

Comment: If you this as-is you'll probably run into STI issues, requiring table "timestampers" to exist. This can be avoided by adding: `self.abstract_class = true` to the TimeStamper class

Answer (score 1):

it is possible to set field names manually:

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Timestamp.html#method-i-timestamp_attributes_for_create

```
def timestamp_attributes_for_create
    [:createdDatetime]
end
```

my answer is duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/a/13457972/1007043 Also, there are info about Rails 5 solution